# Python3 can't open file 'practice1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-3.8

Please help me... I'm a fresh python user. I'm on python 3.8.3, MacOS Sierra 10.12, and VSCode 1.55.0. This error just showed up when I typed the python3 filename.py. But my program worked fine when I simply clicked the run play button.

However there are few python programs I can normally run by typing python3 and the file name.

Another thing is I couldn't even navigate into a folder by typing cd /Users/Aryanadi/Documents/ONLINE COURSES 2020/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wjo0.png)

Everything worked fine last year, I dont know why this is happening to me by now. Maybe error coming from the VS Code? I am attaching the screen shot:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtZ5h.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcOsl.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Million thanks!

Answer (score -1):

PROBLEMS SLOVED! I just learned that to be able to run the python program file in VS Code I must open the folder containing the python code file name with extension py, so I can not just simply open and run the python code in VS Code. The whole foldercontaining the python code file name with extension py must be opened. Thank you!